Essentially measurable function
I was reading through the following text on functional calculus, and in the section of the appendix that introduces the Bochner integral (p. 270), there a mention of "essentially measurable" functions (at the very bottom of p. 270). I obviously know about measurable functions, but not "essentially" ones. There isn't any definition of this in the text, and i can neither find any definition on the internet. Any ideas ? Maybe some sort of measurability up to set of measure $0$ ? Thanks in advance !

Measurable w.r.t. the completion maybe?

@Adayah It seems to be what it is said at the beginning of page 244. If $f=g$ a.e. for some measurable $g$, it seems clear to me that $f$ is measurable w.r.t. the completion, but I am not sure how to construct $g$ in the converse direction.

Fix a countable basis $(B_k)$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and write $f^{-1}[B_k]=E_k \mathbin{\Delta} M_k$ with $E_k$ measurable and $M_k \subseteq N_k$ where $N_k$ is a (measurable) null set. Let $N = \bigcup_k N_k$ and let $g = 0$ on $N$ and $f$ elsewhere. Then $g = f$ a.e. and $g$ is measurable since $g^{-1}[B_k] = E_k \setminus N$ or $E_k \cup N$ depending on if $0 \in B_k$.

The definition can be found on page 244 of the linked text:

A function $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb C$ is essentially measurable if $f$ coincides almost everywhere with a measurable function.


Let me add a subtle point. This means that there exist a measurable set $S\subseteq\Omega$ and a measurable function $g:\Omega\to\mathbb C$ such that (i) $\Omega\setminus S$ has measure $0$; and (ii) $S\subseteq{\omega\in\Omega,|,f(\omega)=g(\omega)}$. Note that the latter set itself need not be measurable!

@triple_sec For me a slightly less confusing way to put it is that the set $\lbrace f\neq g\rbrace$ is contained in (but is not necessarily) a set of measure zero.

It is worth noting that the next sentence from the text says "Equivalently, for each Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ the set $[f \in B]$ is contained in the $\mu$-completion of $\Sigma$." So this is indeed equivalent to being measurable with respect to the completion.
